# Comparing files with different extensions but possibly similar contents

Tags: linux, file-copy

So the problem is that i need to compare and copy files with 2 different extensions say .txt and .doc . These files may have the same name but different contents. If the contents of say play.txt and play.doc were the same then i need to copy the .doc version. However if the contents are different then both files must be copied.

Comment: `.doc` files are not likely to ever have the same contents as `.txt` files, because `.doc` files have a lot of content that is formatting data.  So you will have to use a tool or application that can read that formatting data to do anything with the actual contents of the `.doc` file.  I recommend using LibreOffice manually.  If you need `.txt` files in the future, just stick with `.txt` from the start.

Comment: ok i get that might have been a bit confusing. what if they were both just text files i had to compare?

Comment: Then you would use diff, as in `diff $1.txt $1.doc || cp $1.txt /dir/ ; cp $1.doc /dir`

Answer (score 2):

To compare the files and select one for copying, you'd need to actually compare their *content*. This may prove difficult for a proprietary file format such as `.doc` (in contrast to `.docx`).

You could **first** convert the `.doc` files to text using libreoffice in headless mode:
`libreoffice --headless --convert-to txt:text mydocument.doc`

A **second** step could compare the files, although I doubt that a converted `.doc` would have exactly the same content as the `.txt` version, making it difficult (if not impossible) to compare them programatically.

Answer (score 0):

If both files are text you can use the `diff` command.

```
FILE_ONE=/home/file_one.txt
FILE_TWO=/home/file_two.txt

if [ -n "$(diff $FILE_ONE $FILE_TWO)" ];then
    cp $FILE_ONE /new_place/
    cp $FILE_TWO /new_place/
else
    cp $FILE_ONE /new_place/
fi
```

This checks if `diff` returns anything, if so, the files are different and should both be copied, otherwise it just copies file one.